# How can i access spring remote service via non-spring java application

Tags: java, spring, remote-access

I have a college task where I have to access a Spring Remote Service via a normal Java Application .
In my Server code I've added this method which exports the service :

```
@Bean(name = "/serviceroute")
    HttpInvokerServiceExporter accountService() {
        HttpInvokerServiceExporter exporter = new HttpInvokerServiceExporter();
        exporter.setService( medicalInterfaceImpl);
        exporter.setServiceInterface( MedicalInterface.class );
        return exporter;
    }
```

But I don't know how to access this service with a Client(which is a basic Java Swing Interface) .

Comment: Look for how to Use simple HTTP Request to Remote Service (it can be any based on Java and etc)

Comment: For anyone with the same question, your client should contain a Spring Application which instantiates your remote service,after that you can use your service however you want, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-http-invoker